# keras documentation how to get details of methods and attributes

Tags: methods, keras, attributes

I wanted to know more about `keras` `tokenizer` and a quick google search took me to [this page](https://keras.io/preprocessing/text/) (it was the first link in the gogle search). Why doesn't it list all the methods and attributes? How could I view those? Is there a separate page for it?

I found another [link](https://faroit.github.io/keras-docs/1.2.2/preprocessing/text/). It seems to be official `keras` documentation but for the old version and it lists methods and attributes. I would like to see similar info but for the most recent `keras` version

Comment: The tokenizer is simply not well documented. Maybe you could ask specific questions about it based on the source code.

Answer (score 3):

Keras preprocessing is moved to separate package. The source code is available here: https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/master/keras_preprocessing/text.py

Installing Keras, will also install keras_applications(well-known model architectures) and keras_preprocessing(utilities for working with image, text and sequence data). https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/setup.py (Lines 40,41).

In the python REPL, you can get the listing of all the methods:

[image]

Comment: I couldnt find details of attributes and methods on those pages

Comment: In the GitHub link I provided, I can see 'class Tokenizer' with methods like fit_on_texts, fit_on_sequences, texts_to_sequences etc. I updated the answer with a screenshot. Can you please clarify what is missing?

Comment: i am talking about attributes and methods. if you look at the second link that i have provided, it provides a detailed description such as `document_count: int. Number of documents (texts/sequences) the tokenizer was trained on. Only set after fit_on_texts or fit_on_sequences was called.` The second link has details of all methods and attributes. Your links dont explain that. In your python screenshot, it shows `document_count`, but doesnt explain what it is. I have to perform google search on each of the item in your screenshot..thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

To get the documentation for the **methods** of the `Tokenizer` object you could just do

```
>>> import keras
>>> help(keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer)
```

In the terminal the beginning of the output from the last call looks like this - which is very similar to the documentation of keras 1.2 to which you have referred in your second link:

[image]

For the **attributes** of the `Tokenizer` object I wasn't able to find proper documentation either.

But - as an alternative to Manoj's answer - to just see the different attributes and methods of a `Tokenizer` object you could simply

```
>>> tokenizer = keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer()
>>> dir(tokenizer)
```

for which the output is

```
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'char_level', 'document_count', 'filters', 'fit_on_sequences', 'fit_on_texts', 'index_docs', 'lower', 'num_words', 'oov_token', 'sequences_to_matrix', 'split', 'texts_to_matrix', 'texts_to_sequences', 'texts_to_sequences_generator', 'word_counts', 'word_docs']
```

Answer (score 1):

if you use jupyter notebook, you could prepend the method with ? to get a short description with inputs and like `?methodname` or a ?? to get source code of that method
like `??methodname`

[image]

Comment: could you share an example with a screenshot?

Comment: you can use tab to cycle through methods available in a module, just like an IDE.